# Smarty Iteration and get the previous column in record

Tags: php, smarty, iteration

In my loop, I want to compare the current column in my recordset to the next in order to add an extra blank row if different.

```
{if $smarty.section.row.next.pc_name != $timeblocks[row].pc_name}
    <tr bgcolor="#333333"><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always done these things by checking previous record, like this:

```
{assign var="last" value=""}

{section name=row loop=$rows}
    ...
    {if $last != $timeblocks[row].pc_name}
        <tr bgcolor="#333333"><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        {assign var="last" value=$timeblocks[row].pc_name} {* UPDATE LAST *}
    {/if}
{/section}
```

However, **if you want to maintain your logic**, you can use **[`index_next` section property](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.section.tpl)**, which gives you the next iteration index (unfortunately not the next iteration element, but no problems):

```
{if $timeblocks[$smarty.section.row.index_next].pc_name != $timeblocks[row].pc_name}
    <tr bgcolor="#333333"><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
{/if}
```